# tfp.keras.layers: If the data format is 'channels_first' , can I give the network input shape as 'channels_last'?

Tags: python, tensorflow, shapes, dataformat, tensorflow-probability

My input images have the shape `(4,128,128,128)` , where the data_format is channels_first. In my network, I am using `Convolution3DFlipout` layers which has default `data_format='channels_last'`. When I change the data_format as:

`layer = tfp.layers.Convolution3DFlipout(data_format='channels_first')(input_layer)`

and provide the input shape as:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input

def model(input_shape=(4, 128, 128, 128),optimizer=Adam, initial_learning_rate=5e-4,
                      loss_function=bin_crossentropy, activation_name="sigmoid",metrics=dice_coefficient):

    inputs = Input(input_shape)
    ......
```

I get the following error:

`TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'list'> to Tensor. Contents: [None, 16, 16384, 128]. Consider casting elements to a supported type.`.

1. Why does it return `[None, 16, 16384, 128]` when the layer output should actually be `[None, 16, 128, 128, 128]`. Does anyone know why setting `data_format='channels_first'` in `Convolution3DFlipout()` throws this error?
2. If I provide the input shape as  `(128,128,128,4)` (so that I don't have to change the default data_format) when my data has shape `(4, 128, 128, 128)`, am I wrong?

Comment: @chrissuter could you please have a look at this question? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

`tfp.layers.Convolution3DFlipout()` has

> data_format: A string, one of channels_last (default) or
> channels_first

.

If you reshape your input as (129,128, 128, 4), Then no need to provide data_format argument in `tfp.layers.Convolution3DFlipout`.

Take a look at example below,

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape([128, 128, 128, 4]),
    tfp.layers.Convolution3DFlipout(
        64, kernel_size=5, padding='SAME', activation=tf.nn.relu))
```

Comment: My question is if my data has the input shape (4,128,128,128), then can I feed the network input_shape=(128,128,128,4)?